# How to plot a 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have an array of Clusters using Dimensionality Reduction n = 2 and it is plotted in 2D with the following code:

```
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(24,6))
# labels = ['No Fraud', 'Fraud']
f.suptitle('Clusters using Dimensionality Reduction', fontsize=14)


blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#0A0AFF', label='No Fraud')
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='#AF0000', label='Fraud')


# t-SNE scatter plot
ax1.scatter(X_reduced_tsne[:,0], X_reduced_tsne[:,1], c=(y == 0), cmap='coolwarm', label='No Fraud', linewidths=2)
ax1.scatter(X_reduced_tsne[:,0], X_reduced_tsne[:,1], c=(y == 1), cmap='coolwarm', label='Fraud', linewidths=2)
ax1.set_title('t-SNE', fontsize=14)

ax1.grid(True)

ax1.legend(handles=[blue_patch, red_patch])

# PCA scatter plot
ax2.scatter(X_reduced_pca[:,0], X_reduced_pca[:,1], c=(y == 0), cmap='coolwarm', label='No Fraud', linewidths=2)
ax2.scatter(X_reduced_pca[:,0], X_reduced_pca[:,1], c=(y == 1), cmap='coolwarm', label='Fraud', linewidths=2)
ax2.set_title('PCA', fontsize=14)

ax2.grid(True)

ax2.legend(handles=[blue_patch, red_patch])

# TruncatedSVD scatter plot
ax3.scatter(X_reduced_svd[:,0], X_reduced_svd[:,1], c=(y == 0), cmap='coolwarm', label='No Fraud', linewidths=2)
ax3.scatter(X_reduced_svd[:,0], X_reduced_svd[:,1], c=(y == 1), cmap='coolwarm', label='Fraud', linewidths=2)
ax3.set_title('Truncated SVD', fontsize=14)

ax3.grid(True)

ax3.legend(handles=[blue_patch, red_patch])

plt.show()
```

[This is the 2D plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CW2u.png)

How can I plot n = 3 data in 3D?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib has a pretty easy system for 3d graphing:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
```

This would output:
[image]

Read more: [Documentation on 3D Graphing](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html)